# Две Animation в одном

Tags: java, android, android-animation

У меня проект Компас, в начале проекта включается анимация `ImageView` и работает постоянно. Хочу прикрепить к `ImageView` еще одну `Animation`,что бы `ImageView` опустился на 200(ToYDelta), но не могу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть в виде текста, а не скриншота. Как здесь [задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

AnimatorSet тебе в помощь, но текущие анимации придётся переделать. И посмотри ObjectAnimator- очень удобный класс, анимирует по любым полям класса, главное чтоб геттеры и сеттеры были